# (REACT)Buttons in popup container cause whole container to dissapear

Tags: html, jquery, css, reactjs, popup

I'm using  from 'reactjs-popup' and when I add a button to the content being popup'd and click said button, it causes my entire popup container to dissapear. I don't want this to happen and I'm not sure how to prevent it. Relevant code:

```
const createCard = (src, text, price, key) => (
    <Popup
      trigger={
        <button className="popup-card">
          <div className="card">
            <img className="card-image" src={src} alt="card-img" />
            <h3 className="card-name">{text}</h3>
            <p className="card-price">{`$${price}`}</p>
          </div>
        </button>
      }
      key={key}
    >
      {popupContainer}
    </Popup>
  );

  const popupContainer = () => (
    <div className="popup-container">
      <button
        type="button"
        className="popup-input-buttons"
        onClick={subtractItem}
      >
        -
      </button>
      <input type="text" className="popup-input"></input>
      <button type="button" className="popup-input-buttons" onClick={addItem}>
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

State:

```
    const [items, setItems] = useState(0);
        
    // Manipulate items state
    const addItem = () => setItems(items + 1);
          
    const subtractItem = () => setItems(items - 1);
```

EDIT: When changing the add/subtractItem functions to:

```
    addItem = (e) => {
    e.target.preventDefault();
    setItem(item + 1);
    }
```

The popup container stays open onClick, but the setItem state setter no longer works.

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code. Here is a simple code snippet: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-mestorf-d627zp?file=/src/App.js and I can click on the button and the popup stays.

Answer (score 1):

try adding `closeOnDocumentClick` prop to your Popup, by default it is set to `true`, so it may cause you to close your popup if you click on any contents in the popup. Change to `false` should fix the problem.

```
<Popup
      ...
      closeOnDocumentClick={false}
    >
      {popupContainer}
</Popup>
```

Here is the doc: https://react-popup.elazizi.com/component-api#closeondocumentclick

> ```
> closeOnDocumentClick# bool | true
> ```
>
> Close popup when the overlay clicked

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work, however when I remove the onClick property from my input buttons, the form popup properly stays open after clicking a button. Any idea why that might be happening, so I can properly call my addItem/subtractItem functions onClick?

Comment: could you specify which ```onClick``` prop? Because I dont see any ```button``` inside your ```input```? Do you mean plus and minus button?

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant the buttons in the popup container.

Comment: At first, I think it might be caused by form submission, but you clearly set your button to button type, so it should not cause any issue.

Comment: I see that you are passing in ```(src, text, price, key)``` dynamically, could you explain what you are trying to do here?

Comment: I am creating shopping item cards that show the item's picture, name and price. The cards are stored in an array, so that's why I'm passing they key.

Comment: Do you see any error in the console while click on the button? also checkout the code snippet I posted in the OP's comment.

Comment: No error in the console. Could it be a CSS issue? or maybe an specific issue with firefox?

Comment: I don't think it's the CSS or a browser issue. Right now, one problem comes to my mind is that if you look into the code snippet, the only two things I did differently than your code is: (1) I didn't pass in ```src, text, price, key```, which could've caused a re-render on your component on a state change, (2)  I wrapped your popup container inside a functional component ```<PopupContainer />```. I would say try (2) and see what happen.

Comment: So, I think you're right on the idea that passing `src, text, price, key` is what's causing the issue. After removing them the popup worked properly. Now I have to figure out how to reorganize my code more properly. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved after removing the Popup react component from my createCard() function and instead making a function purely for the Popup component.

```
const createCard = (src, text, price, key) => (
    <div className="card">
      <img className="card-image" src={src} alt="card-img" />
      <h3 className="card-name">{text}</h3>
      <p className="card-price">{`$${price}`}</p>
    </div>
  );

  function popupCard(card) {
    return (
      <Popup
        trigger={
          <button type="button" className="popup-card">
            {card}
          </button>
        }
      >
        <div>
          <PopupContainer addItem={addItem} subtractItem={subtractItem} />
        </div>
      </Popup>
    );
  }
```